# mysql JDBC Connection NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, runtime-error

I am trying to test mySQL JDBC connection on a windows 2008 server. I have downloaded the JDBC driver and it created a jar file at "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector J\mysql-connector-java-5.1.34-bin.jar".
When I am running a small program to test my jdbc connection , I am getting "NoClassDefFound" error.
What am i missing here?

I did set up jdbc jar in classpath

```
C:\>echo %CLASSPATH%
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector J\mysql-connector-java-5.1.34-bin.jar;
```

I have placed the jar in same location where I have my DBDemo.java (C:\test)

***DemoDB.java***

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Properties;
public class DBDemo
{
// The JDBC Connector Class.
private static final String dbClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
// Connection string. emotherearth is the database the program
// is connecting to. You can include user and password after this
// by adding (say) ?user=paulr&password=paulr. Not recommended!
private static final String CONNECTION =
                      "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/emotherearth";
public static void main(String[] args) throws
                         ClassNotFoundException,SQLException
{
    System.out.println(dbClassName);
    // Class.forName(xxx) loads the jdbc classes and
    // creates a drivermanager class factory
    Class.forName(dbClassName);
    // Properties for user and password. Here the user and password are both 'paulr'
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.put("user","paulr");
    p.put("password","paulr");
    // Now try to connect
    Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION,p);
    System.out.println("It works !");
    c.close();
}
}
```

***Error ***

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin>java c:\test\DBDemo
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: c:\test\DBDemo
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: c:\test\DBDemo
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
 Could not find the main class: c:\test\DBDemo.  Program will exit.
```

Comment: What are the contents of that bin file? `jar tvvf` or open it with your favorite zip file tool.

Answer (score 1):

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector J\mysql-connector-java-5.1.34-bin.jar;
```

Your `CLASSPATH` seems to be not having `.` that is the current working directory where the `DBDemo` would be there. So add `.` also to your `CLASSPATH`. After that your `CLASSPATH` will be like

```
.;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector J\mysql-connector-java-5.1.34-bin.jar;
```

#### EDIT

Also try extracting the contents of `mysql-connector-java-5.1.34-bin.jar` into a folder and change the `CLASSPATH` according to that.

Comment: Did the same. It didnt help

Comment: are you using any ide

Comment: No. I am doing it from cmd line

Comment: @sravs448 have you tried extracting the contents of jar

Answer (score 1):

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

One of the places java tries to find your `.class` file is your current directory. So if your `.class` file is in `c:\test\`, you should change your current directory to that.

To change your directory, type the following command at the prompt and press Enter:

```
cd c:\test\
```

Also

```
set CLASSPATH = .;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector J\mysql-connector-java-5.1.34-bin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\lib\tools.jar;

set PATH = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin
```

Executing your program using this command should correct the problem:

```
c:\test>java DemoDB
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem can have several causes, but one of the most common is that the classes or dependencies cannot see each other, you must verify the import of each class or dependency, if you have renamed packages, classes or dependencies then the JVM cannot find the class or dependency sought.